# Sublime-text 3 Vintage Mode mapping

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

Please help with mapping in VintageMode.
I want to avoid <kbd>Esc</kbd> key
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key

ho to map these keys?

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> opens a new line below the one you are currently editing,
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> appends to the end of the current line,
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> pastes at the current insert location.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> moves up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the [Default keymap](https://github.com/sublimehq/Vintage/blob/master/Default.sublime-keymap) and copy the entries you want to have into your User keymap. Afterwards prefix the keybinding with `alt+` and if it is uppercase `alt+shift+` and the lowercase char. Change the context from `"key": "setting.command_mode"` to `"key": "setting.command_mode", "operator": "equal", "operand": false`. Do this for every keybinding you want and it should work.

Example:

```js
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+a"], "command": "enter_insert_mode", "args":
    {"insert_command": "move_to", "insert_args": {"to": "hardeol"} },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode", "operator": "equal", "operand": false}]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

To create custom Key Bindings use `Menu > Preferences > Key Bindings`, see [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) for detailed information on key Bindings.

Here is some [documentation on customising Vintage](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/vintage.html).

To see the Vintage default Key Bindings, take a look at the Vintage package [bundled with Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/packages.html). Though out-of-date, the sublimehq has a [Vintage package on github](https://github.com/sublimehq/Vintage).

Also try [Vintageous](https://packagecontrol.io/search/Vintageous).